# Not able to retrieve value of parameters from JSP page

Tags: java, javascript

Suppose

**home.jsp** code contain a button like

```
<input name="R" onclick="del(<%=rs.getString("VDB")%>)" type="radio" value="<%=rs.getString("VDB")%>" />
```

//**note**: i am passing value of VDB in del()

it is calling javascript as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function del(delno)
{
 var ff = document.vendorform;

 var url = "delete.jsp?+vendor="+delno;
 window.navigate("delete_vendor.jsp?+vendor="+delno);

 //window.location.href="delete_vendor.jsp?+vendor="+delno;
 //ff.method = "POST";
 //ff.action ="delete_vendor.jsp?+vendor="+delno;
 //ff.submit();
}//i have used 3 methods to redirect to delete.jsp
```

delete.jsp :
on this page i want to retrieve value of **vendor** i used :

```
String D1=request.getParameter("vendor");
```

But getting null value. 
Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = "delete.jsp?+vendor="+delno;
```

you have inserted wrong string `+vendor`. it should be only `vendor` in url.

```
var url = "delete.jsp?vendor="+delno;
```

Comment: can u please tell about session why after clicking a link(anchor tag) my session values get null

Comment: you may invalidate the session by session.invalidate() which remove session from server.

Comment: but i have to use session values to retrieve data from database..any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "+" before the word vendor. Change

```
var url = "delete.jsp?+vendor="+delno;
```

To

```
var url = "delete.jsp?vendor="+delno;
```